# Не устанавливаются драйверы nvidia ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, nvidia

почему то не могу поставить драйвер, выдаёт не понятную ошибку

> dpkg-divert: ошибка: несовпадение с пакетом   при удалении «отклонение
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 из-за libnvidia-gl-396»   найдено
>   «отклонение /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 в
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.distrib из-за nvidia-340» dpkg:
>   ошибка при обработке архива
>   /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-KH1cx9/11-libnvidia-gl-396_396.24.02-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1_amd64.deb
>   (--unpack):  new libnvidia-gl-396:amd64 package pre-installation
>   script subprocess returned error exit status 2

Answer (score 5):

Нашёл решение:

Посмотреть все зависимости `nvidia-340`

```
dpkg-divert --list | grep nvidia-340
```

Затем для каждой из них выполнить

```
dpkg-divert --remove /your/path
```

`/your/path` - путь, на который ругается `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1`

```
apt --fix-broken install 
apt update
apt upgrade
ubuntu-drivers devices
ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

Затем перезагрузите систему.